# how to receive the public IP address of client in onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to write an extension to block requests to a specific website according to the IP address.
I've already written this code that blocks all requests related to `*://*.google.com/*`. My question is how can I block requests in `onBeforeRequest` based on the IP addresses?

```
var urls = [
    '*://*.google.com/*',
  ];

  var types = ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']
  
  var response = async function(d){
    return true
  };
  
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(response, { urls: urls, types: types }, ['blocking'] );
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be interested in the public IP address of the *server* in this case?

Comment: No, I like to filter requests based on my own IP address. It's for cases that my VPN connection is not running properly.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The [documentation for `onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest) shows that this isn't information that's available to an extension at this point.

This makes sense, however, as at this point in the lifecycle the browser most likely hasn't made any DNS queries for the IP address of the server at the domain - it simply wouldn't be able to know without making those queries.